# Unable to parse different ids from json using scrapy whereas I got success using requests

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to parse different ids from some json response using scrapy but I can't make it possible whereas I get success using requests module. I'm trying to get the ids of different [article numbers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGHVh.jpg) from this [website](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/productsearch?psnid=13204&lc=en-WW). Ids look like `1397099`, `539728` e.t.c which requests version can fetch flawlessly.

Using requests (succeeded):

```
import json
import requests

link = "https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?"
 
payload = {
    'language': 'en',
    'region': 'ww',
    'networks': 'Internet',
    'productNodePath': '/13204/',
    '$top': '20'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.89 Safari/537.36'
    r = s.get(link,params=payload)
    for item in r.json()['Products']:
        print(item['Id'])
```

Using scrapy (failed):

```
import scrapy
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class SiemensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens'

    start_link = "https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?"

    payload = {
        'language': 'en',
        'region': 'ww',
        'networks': 'Internet',
        'productNodePath': '/13204/',
        '$top': '20'
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        first_req = f'{self.start_link}{urlencode(self.payload)}'
        yield scrapy.Request(first_req,callback=self.parse)
    
    def parse(self,response):
        for item in json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())['Products']:
            print(item['Id'])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    })
    c.crawl(SiemensSpider)
    c.start()
```

When I run the scrapy code, I get some response which are not json and that is why I get this error `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError`.

***How can I parse ids from json using scrapy?***

Comment: I've had a go at replicating the request, it;s abit strange that requests picks up the correct json whereas scrapy doesnt. I don't have access to the soruce of the request ie the headers/cookies but would it be worth trying to pass those as well. Try replicating the rqeuests as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with the headers.

I opened [one of the links](https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?language=en&region=ww&networks=Internet&productNodePath=%2F13204%2F&%24top=20) via a browser and I saw that xml was being returned.

I modified the headers of the spider so that it requests json and it worked as expected:

```
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        first_req = f'{self.start_link}{urlencode(self.payload)}'
        yield scrapy.Request(first_req, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)
```

Full code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from urllib.parse import urlencode
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class SiemensSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'siemens'

    start_link = "https://support.industry.siemens.com/webbackend/api/ProductSupport/ProductSearch?"

    payload = {
        'language': 'en',
        'region': 'ww',
        'networks': 'Internet',
        'productNodePath': '/13204/',
        '$top': '20'
    }

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    }


    def start_requests(self):
        first_req = f'{self.start_link}{urlencode(self.payload)}'
        yield scrapy.Request(first_req, callback=self.parse, headers=self.headers)

    def parse(self, response):
        for item in json.loads(response.text)['Products']:
            print(item['Id'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = CrawlerProcess({
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; ) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36',
    })
    c.crawl(SiemensSpider)
    c.start()
```

I imagine that the `requests` library must request json by default.